# Why isn't (20 >) . length . take 10 === const True

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, pattern-matching, lazy-evaluation

### tl;dr

Isn't the fact that `20 < length $ take 10 $ whatever` requires `whatever` to successfully pattern patch a list (at least either `[]` or `(_:_)`) a "lack" of laziness?

Or, in other words, why isn't `(20 >) . length . take 10 === const True`, so that applying either of them to anything requires no evaluation of the argument whatsoever?

Is `(20 >) . length . take 10 !== const True` a necessity? Or a design choice? In either case, why?

### Foreword

This is a follow up to [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72133599/5825294).

There I asked about why `fix error` prints `*** Exception:`  repeatedly and infinitely.

The answer was satisfactory.

### My lucubration

However, I played around a bit with `ghci` and realized that `take 0 $ fix error` expectedly  returns `""`, and `length $ take 0 $ fix error` returns `0`.

On the other hand, the following prints the `*** Exception:`  infinite flow:

```hs
20 > (length $ take 10 $ fix error)
```

I understand that ***if*** even one single elmenent of `fix error` is computed (attempted to, actually), the result is what it is, but my question is: why is the evaluation of any of them needed in the first place, **in that specific expression**? After all, `length $ take 10 $ whatever` can't be other than `<= 10`, hence `< 20`, so the expression should evaluate to `True`.

Actually, I see that `20 > (length $ take 10 $ [fix error])` returns immediately with `True`. Probably the whole point is that `take 10` expects to work on a `[a]`, and so `length $ take 10 $ [fix error]` doens't need to evaluate `fix error` to be sure it's working on a `[a]`. Indeed, I've verified that `20 > (length $ take 10 $ undefined)` errors too (even though not with an infinitely repeating error), whereas `20 > (length $ take 10 $ [undefined])` returns with `True`.

Maybe that's what [Willem Van Onsem meant in this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72133599/what-is-fix-in-haskell-and-why-does-fix-error-print-an-infinite-string-and/72133643?noredirect=1#comment127469056_72133643).

Anyway, since I can write the expression above as

```hs
((20 >) . length . take 10) $ fix error
```

I would be tempted to say that

```hs
(20 >) . length . take 10 === const True
```

and hence I'd say it's reasonable for `((20 >) . length . take 10) $ fix error` to return `True` just like `const True $ fix error` returns `True`.

But that's not the case. Why?

Comment: Are you asking about why you observe the things you do in Haskell, or are you asking about what behavior could in principle exist if we were designing a fresh Haskell-like language from scratch?

Comment: @DanielWagner the latter.

Comment: Okay. Suppose we have made a hypothetical specification that is flexible enough about the meaning of programs that the compiler is permitted to perform the rewrite `length (take 10 x) < 20` -> `True` if it can discover it. What is your implementation plan for making a compiler capable of discovering and performing that rewrite?

Comment: Is the goal symbolic computation or proving properties of some programs? If so, there are paradigms in which the statement `(20 >) . length . take 10 === const True` is provable and machine verifiable (e.g. Agda, Coq). Or do you want the compiler to "fix" some types of programs for you? If so, the really boring answer to your question: it works this way because the language assigns consistent and predictable operational semantics to programs, and this choice of operational semantics which has `take 10 undefined = undefined` also allows for a broad class of programs with real-world use.

Comment: ... Nevertheless, it is not inconceivable that in todays Haskell you could define different symbols with the names `length` and `take` such that `length . take 10 $ [1,2, ...]` computes to `10` and also `(<20) . length . take 10 $ undefined` computes to `True`. But there is no canonical or universal way to do so. *How* you define such symbols depends entirely on what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behaviour you're seeing is much more to do with `length` and `>` than with `take`. `length` has to return a *specific* number, and `(20 >)` can only be run when supplied with a specific number. What number do you imagine is being processed in the middle of your pipeline?

You acknowledge that `length $ take 10 $ fix error` is (and should be) bottom. There is not even one single element of the list `fix error` that can be looked at before encountering an error so there is no number that could be returned that is an accurate measure of the list's length. (It might be tempting to say its length could be zero as there aren't any elements there, but that would imply that `fix error` is equal to `[]`, which isn't true either. Really asking for its length is simply an error.)

However, you now want to feed that bottom value into `(20 >)` and expect the result `True`. But bottoms are interchangeable, so this would require that `20 > undefined` is also `True`. And indeed, it would require `(20 >) $ length $ take 50 $ fix error` to *also* be `True`.

Your intuition seems to be that `length . take 10` is not capable of returning a value greater than 10, so `(20 >) . length . take 10` should be `const True`, and thus shouldn't need to examine its input. You've obviously noticed that that isn't accurate for current Haskell, but I don't think it would be desirable behaviour anyway. My intuition is that `(20 >)` needs a *specific* input number that is less than 20 in order to return `True`; a vague notion that its input can't be a larger number isn't good enough. If its input is an error (any error) then neither `True` nor `False` is an accurate return value.

Note that `length $ take 0 $ fix error` is a very different case. `take` is defined equivalently to this:

```
take n _
  | n <= 0  = []
take _ [] = []
take n (x:xs) = x : take (n - 1) xs
```

It checks whether the number of elements to be taken is zero (or less) *before* it examines any of the list, and if so it can return a specific concrete list `[]` without examining the input list (and therefore without triggering any errors from `fix error` or `undefined`). Then `length` can measure `[]` and return `0`, which is less than `20`.

Similarly, `length $ take 10 $ [fix error]` works because `take 10` can return a list of length one without examining any of the elements **inside** the list (and thus without triggering the error), and `length` can measure that list and return `1`, which is less than `20`.

Both of these cases never actually require a specific value for any property that is undefined, but your original case does (the `length` of an error). It's not to do with "ensuring we're working on `[a]`", just whether your answer depends on a value that is undefined.

Answer (score 4):

`take 10` has to determine if its argument is a `[]` or `(:)` value.

`const True` does not.

---

`length` is strict, in that it has to iterate over its entire argument. Composition doesn't mean that it only has to iterate over enough values to get a number big enough to falsify `(20 >)`.

Comment: As a consequence of this the two functions are denotationally different. It's not a good idea in general to perform program modifications that change the denotation of a program behind the programmer's back, even if all you're doing is making the program more defined.

Answer (score 3):

> After all, length $ take 10 $ whatever can't be other than <= 10 [...]

Is not correct in Haskell. The length function may in general crash or go into an infinite loop. In both cases it would not give a valid integer as result, and that lack of valid integer can not be compared to 10. In general, evaluating an arbitrary expression may result in either a value for example (1::Int) or [bottom](https://wiki.haskell.org/Bottom). Where bottom generalizes over all reasons why the expression may not result in a value.

The expression `20 < length $ take 10 $ whatever`, therefore must evaluate to either `True` or bottom and for the compiler `False` is even an option. As you have seen both `True` and `bottom` are valid results. By contrast, `const True whatever` is different as it always evaluates in `True` without evaluating `whatever`.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted, you could define an "unsafe" `take`-like function that is guaranteed to return exactly the specified number of elements.

```
tack :: Natural -> [a] -> [a]
tack 0 _ = []
tack n ~(x:xs) = x : tack (n-1) xs
-- Alternatively,
tack n xs = head xs : tack (n-1) (tail xs)
```

`tack 10 undefined` will now be the list `replicate 10 undefined`, so there's no difficulty calculating that it's less than 20.

Going back to your question, the list `take 10 undefined` *has no length*, in any sense, so we can't say it's less than 20. Even using lazy natural numbers won't help.

```
data Nat = Z | S Nat deriving (Eq, Ord)
instance Num Nat where
  fromInteger 0 = Z
  fromInteger n = S (fromInteger (n - 1))
  ...

length :: [a] -> Nat
length = foldr S Z

take :: Nat -> [a] -> [a]
take (S n) (x : xs) = x : take n xs
take _ _ = []
```

Now we will have `length (take 10) (() : undefined) >= 1 === True`, but we still can't say it's less than 20, because "it's at least one" is all the information that exists about that length.